# How to Export to/Import from GeoGebra?

Tags: export, import, geometry

I'd like to convert geometric figures between Mathematica and [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: have you tried via .eps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GeoGebra files are in zipped XML so you can replicate GeoGebra drawings in Mathematica - concurrent with every GeoGebra Save.

I wrote a reader of GeoGebra XML and used it for exploring geometry. All symbols in GG can be used in Mathematica except those with "'" or "_" , the latter gets Subscript[].

Symbolic equations with GG symbols can be written in Mathematica. To get the evaluation use the function val[].

```
{xx, Sqrt[a b - ( a b c^2)/(a + b)^2]} // val

{9.22407, 9.22407}
```

Or if you don't bother to read values

```
AB == GD (1 + b/xx) + FD (1 + a/xx) // val

True
```

I've only tried a few primitive drawings since I was more interested in applying Mathematica computation to geometry {drawings}, but all the data is in the XML.

Comment: Where is the package? Can you show step by step conversion from GG to MMA?

Comment: "I wrote a reader of GeoGebra XML and used it for exploring geometry." Sounds like a non-trivial undertaking. Would you mind sharing?

Comment: @Douglas Kubler, as the others have stated, that seems like a complex undertaking and a tool which would be useful to many.  Would you please consider sharing the code with us all? source? or do you have that as a GitHub or SourceForge project already?  Thank you in advance for your consideration of this request.

Comment: @EricMarceau I think I misunderstood. I never interfaces GeoGebra with Mathematica. I would also like to see the GeoGebra importer Douglas wrote, even if imperfect, as I have been using GeoGebra regularly for the last couple of months.

Comment: Sorry, @Szabolcs, I misunderstood.

Comment: For anyone interested, I posted a Q&A on creating a custom Geogebra file structure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268642/is-there-an-example-showing-how-the-geogebra-xml-file-is-structured-so-i-can-wri/77268645#77268645).